# Long variable assignment recommended wrapping

Tags: python, pep8, word-wrap

I have the following assignments in my `__init__()` method:

```
self.seat, self.feet, self.backrest, self.stabilizer_bar, self.packaged = False
```

I would like to make it compliant to PEP8, but the line is too long. I thought about using one line for each assignment, but it doesn't feel pythonic to type `False` 5 times.

What's the recommended way to wrap the line above?

**EDIT**:

I've changed `False * 5` to `False` thanks to your comments. But still, how do I wrap the line?

Comment: `False * 5` doesn't do what you think it does. You want `self.seat = self.feet = self.backrest = ... = False`.

Comment: Or rather, `self.seat = self.feet = self.backrest = \[newline]... = False`

Comment: I don't think typing `False` 5 times is unpythonic.

Comment: How about: `self.seat, self.feet, self.backrest, self.stabilizer_bar, self.packaged = (False,) * 5`

Comment: `False * 5` is the same as `0 * 5`, which is `0`. The code you have written will give you a `TypeError`.

Answer (score 2):

Try wrapping the left side in parentheses, then splitting it. That usually works.

```
def __init__(self):
    (self.seat, self.feet, self.backrest, 
    self.stabilizer_bar, self.packaged) = False, False, False, False, False
```

I don't know how this behaves in actual production code, but a quick run in PyScripter returns no error.

Comment: @ValentinLorentz, don't we usually call the parenthesis 'round brackets' anyway? That certainly complies with the 'brackets' naming convention :D

Comment: Please try and improve the answer, otherwise this should have been a comment.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid, do you mean the absence of `self` and the False * 5? I was only trying to show what I meant with 'wrapping the left side in parenthesis'. However, I do agree that it might confuse some people. I'll go edit that.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a really long list of assignments, why not trying:

```
def __init__(self):
    for prop in ['seat', 'feet', 'backrest', 'stabilizer_bar', 'packaged']:
        setattr(self, prop, False)
```

Comment: It makes the syntax too complicated; there will be only 5 assignments.

Answer (score 0):

In this specific case, I'd write the assignments line by line:

```
self.seat = False
self.feet = False
self.backrest = False
self.stabilizer_bar = False
self.packaged = False
```

Now assuming rather than `False` you have a function returning a tuple, I'd write it this way:

```
(self.seat, self.feet, self.backrest,
 self.stabilizer_bar, self.packaged) = my_function()
```

as in [TrueError's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22435084/4653485).